# ESD protection for MCU pins

Tags: power-electronics, esd, tvs

I am working on a MCU project. The MCU pins have a limit of 3.6 V and the Voh is 2.86V.

I am trying to find a TVS diode that could save the pins !!.
I am getting TVS diodes with 3.3 Vrm .
I believe the clamping voltage must be 3.6 but I can't find a diode which satisfies this requirement.

Can't anyone suggest me a workaround?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unrealistic to clamp to 3.6 V with a standoff voltage of 3.3 V using only an ESD diode. Realistic clamping voltages for worst case ESD strikes, are ~10..20 V.

You then place a **series resistor** between the TVS diode and the MCU pin to limit current to the allowable level given in the MCU datasheet.